# Passing a value to another class and displaying it on that view controller

Tags: ios, swift, option-type

I have two `.swift` classes. **Test.swift** and **Start.swift**.

**Start.swift** has a func called `outputPercentage`. See below.

```
var startClass = StartView()


class StartView: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet var testProg: UILabel!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
            super.viewDidLoad()
            testClass.sendpct()
        }

    func outputPercentage(pct: Int32) {
       let pctTxt = String(pct)
       print("Test Progress: ", pctTxt as Any)
       testProg.text = "Test" //pctTxt! + " / 100"
    }
}
```

**testProg** is a `UILabel`.

The func below is in **Test.swift** and passes an Int32 value back to the function above in **Start.swift**, like so:

```
var testClass = TestView()

class TestView {

  func sendpct() {
     var percentComplete : Int32 = 0;
     startClass.outputPercentage(pct: percentComplete)
  }

}
```

The line below gives me an "**Unexpected optional nil**" error.

```
testProg.text = pct_txt! + " / 100"
```

The `UILabel` is all set up correctly as I can set it elsewhere in the class, this error only occurs when the value has been passed from the other class.

How do I correctly output the value to my `UILabel`?

Comment: `textProg` is almost certainly nil - How does your `Start` instance get a reference to the `Test` instance - how is `testProg` assigned a value? .   You should also say `let percentText = String(pct)` - There is no need for your variable to be an optional, no need for it to be a variable and by convention you should use camelCase instead of _ in Swift

Comment: `var startClass = StartView()` is not how you need to create an instance of a view controller from a storyboard.

Comment: Yes, testProg is nil. If I call testProg.txt = "test" in the viewDidLoad function it works just fine. So, I believe I've set up the outlet correctly. However, when I use it in the outputPercentage function it fails

Comment: So the fact I can call functions in that class from the test class is throwing me off

Comment: Also make sure you are not calling `outputPercentage` before the `viewDidLoad` of `Start` is called.

Comment: outputPercentage get's called from the Test class, which only gets called after the viewDidLoad in Start, so that seems to be okay.

Comment: @rmaddy how should I create an instance of the start class then? As I said I assumed that was working fine as I could call functions from the other class without issue. If you think this is causing my issue then I'm happy to try another (the correct) way?

Comment: You shouldn't really tightly couple the two classes.  Simply have `sendPct` return the `Int32` and then `StartView` can update its label.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is better to use Delegate for your case.

In **Start.swift**

```swift
import UIKit

protocol StartDelegate: class {
    func outputPercentage(pct: Int32)
}

class StartView: UIViewController, StartDelegate {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
        var test = Test()
        test.startDelegate = self
        test.sendpct()
    }

    // MARK: - Delegate Methods

    func outputPercentage(pct: Int32) {
        print(pct)
    }

}
```

In **Test.swift**

```swift
class Test {

    weak var startDelegate: StartDelegate?

    func sendpct() {
        if let startDelegate = startDelegate {
            var percentComplete : Int32 = 0;
            startDelegate.outputPercentage(pct: percentComplete)
        }
    }

}
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thank you, that helped a lot and has got me where I need to be!